# Memory usage required for storing a list of functions vs. storing a matrix?

Tags: r, memory

As far as memory goes, is it more expensive to store a list of functions or a list of arrays in R? Here is an example

```
n=1000
x.mat = matrix(rnorm(n^2,0,1),n,n)
z=apply(x.mat, 2, approxfun)
> object.size(z)
11736040 bytes
> object.size(x.mat)
8000200 bytes

n=10000
x.mat = matrix(rnorm(n^2,0,1),n,n)
z=apply(x.mat, 2, approxfun)
> object.size(z)
117360040 bytes
> object.size(x.mat)
800000200 bytes
```

It looks like if your data is really large it takes less memory to store it as a function, even if that function returns the same list of points. Is there any general rule of thumb as to when to store your data using functions vs. the actual data points themselves (of course it takes time to actually compute these functions, and perhaps more time to evaluate them to achieve relevant data)? Maybe this is a really silly question, but I couldn't find anything about it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `object.size` is deceiving you here, since it doesn't take into account things stored in environments. Consider this function generator that keeps a long vector in its environment:

```
g =
function(){
 a = 1:10000
 foo = function(){ sum(a) }
 foo
}


> f=g()
> object.size(f)
4160 bytes
```

pretty small, but still stores those 10,000 numbers:

```
> f()
[1] 50005000
```

where's that at? Here:

```
> object.size(with(environment(f),a))
40040 bytes
```

To get a better idea of the size, save it without compression:

```
> save(f,file="f.Data",compress=FALSE)
> file.info("f.Data")$size
[1] 41368
```

Comment: There's some discussion about why `object.size()` works that way at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#object.size